# How to empty the GET values from a MySQL/jQuery ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

If you do an ajax call to retrieve info from a MySQL database and you time the function so it runs every X seconds, I am a bit confused about where do the GET values reside, in order to empty them.

I have this code in  `test.js`:

```
var fill = function () {
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "refresh.php",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function( data ) {
    $( "#tb" ).append( data );
        setTimeout( fill, 5000);
        }
 });
 } ;
```

and in `refresh.php` I have the SQL query to retrieve the info. After the query, I setting the table like this:

```
    printf( "<tr><td>".$row['name'].
"</td><td>".$row['surname'].
"</td><td>".$row['phone'].
"</td><td>".$row['date'].
"</td></td></tr>");
```

How can I stop the table from populating the same row every 5 seconds? I can pass the `$row['name']` values to regular php values if needed, but I don't fully get in which moment I should empty them.

Answer (score 1):

There might be another solution to this, but I think that my problem could be easily solved by removing the contents of the table before adding another. For instance:

```
var fill = function () {
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "refresh.php",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#tb').empty().append(data);
        }
     });
 };

 setInterval(fill, 5000);
```

You can also make use of `setInterval()` so that you don't need to define a timeout on every execution.

That will do.

Thanks!

Comment: This will not work. With your suggestion, the `#tb` DOM element will be completely removed! Please check the docs on [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/). I think you're looking for [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)